# R Leaflet: like addCircleMarker but with different geometric shapes

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to do an interactive html map with R library leaflet based on markers, whose size and color are also based on other variables. The function addCircleMarkers do the trick perfectly. However, I would like two more geometric simple shapes: squares and triangles, for example.

Is there a way to trick the function to achieve that?